# How to implement TTL on column in DynamoDB?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

After reading DynamoDB(DDB) doc, I know there is only builtin TTL for item/row. Then I wonder if there is a convenient way to implement TTL for column? When a TTL expires, the value in the column of an item (if any) will be eliminated. The general use case is that some field of a row is of limited durability. TTL ensures robustness of a program's business logic.

I learnt that there is DDB trigger using AWS lambda but the limitation is that AWS lambda only deals with DDB stream (of item update). If an item sits silently in the table for a long time, the column of interest in the item will not be erased after an expected TTL. Please correct me if I miss something.

I know that one can add a job to poll DDB periodically. I don't like the idea as that is a significant burden for DDB as the job needs to scan DDB (index) and the scan could be time consuming depending on the size of a DDB table of interest and is a source of data contention.

Regards,

Jun

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Amit mentioned, DynamoDB doesn't provide a mechanism to enable TTL on a column.

That said, I can see that this could be built on top of DynamoDB.

I haven't tried this, so this is simply theory, but if one wanted to TTL a column;

Imagine two tables: 
a. Your current table you wish to TTL a column (Lets call this Original)
b. A new table your TTL logic will be based off (Lets call this TTL Table)

1. Create a new TTL table, to trigger the column based TTLs off, and associate a Lambda to this.
2. Tie a Lambda trigger to the Original table, you wish to TTL a column, and on every event, Perform a PUT operation on the TTL Table with the following data:
   a. The Primary Key from the original table
   b. TTL time
   c. Attribute to remove from original table
3. When the TTL expires on the TTL table, you can trigger the removal of the column from the original table, based on the Primary Key, and the Attribute.

It would seem possible to build, but I would recommend testing it thoroughly.

HTH

Comment: Thanks Abhaya for the answer. I imagine it works. I learnt from another source that one can configure ddb trigger by aws lamdba on a scheduled event(cloudwatch event) to scan thru the table index to clean up stale column value. Based on the tradeoff between space and time, one can pick up either your proposal or the other one I mentioned here.

Answer (score 0):

By default DynamoDB, doesn't provide a mechanism to enable TTL on a column, please refer https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/time-to-live-ttl-how-to.html on more information on how to enable TTL on dynamoDB.

Other solution which you mentioned is obviously not effective and you will end up paying a lot to AWS, if you apply those solution.

**Note :- DynamoDB is not a caching solution, where TTL is very basic requirement, if you want some functionality which is based on TTL, then you should build a cache on top of DynamoDB(AWS provide elastic cache, under which you can use either memcache or redis) and implement a TTL over there.** ,

Comment: Thanks Amit for your answer. The limited durability in my use case is at least 24 hours (it could be days in general) so I guess cache is not an option. The other reasons that I choose not to use cache is that application needs to build distributed lock on top of cache and there is the problem of cache db consistency. Even if any solution of cache has the builtin distributed lock, the app still needs to deal with cache/db consistency issue. Btw, cache has to deal with runtime replacement problem.